# Laravel Vue click event not respond in my vue component

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

"@click event not respond"

also i tried @click.native & @click.prevent
and still nothing happen
[this is the example of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmVps.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `console.log` instead alert and check browser's console.

Comment: Here is a simple example about click event
https://jsfiddle.net/6u2bwnat/
Try to understand what is wrong in your. In the image it looks correct, but I can not see the whole enviroment

Comment: thank you so much i really appriciate your help keep coding god bless you problem solve